# Lazy propagation range update

Tags: segment-tree, lazy-propagation

I was reading lazy  propagation on GFG and it says following for range update

> For example consider the node with value 27 in above diagram, this node stores sum of values at indexes from 3 to 5. If our update query is for range 2 to 5, then we need to update this node and all descendants of this node
>   [Segment Tree Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHodu.png)

I don't understand if the range is 2 to 5 why are we supposed to update only 27 and not other nodes which also contain index = 2 in their ranges

[Link to the article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lazy-propagation-in-segment-tree/)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, could you provide a link to the article.

With lazy propagation you would have to update the node with value 3 and the node with value 27 to process the update query in range [2, 5]. However, you only implicitly update the subtree of the node with value 27, by updating the lazy value of the node with value 27. I assume the text just doesn't mention the node with value 2, but from what you have provided the updates of nodes which contains index 2 are not explicitly excluded.

Comment: Thanx for replying, i have added the article link